# prevent entry in Password KeyChain

Tags: git, macos, aws-codecommit

While performing any operation using Git on my MAC, I see an entry in `Password KeyChain`.

Problem is, I am working with `AWS CodeCommit` and it does not like entry in Password Keychain so I have to manually go and delete `git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` entry from `password keychain`.

Any operation using `git` adds the entry again and I have to delete that again.

Is there way to prevent git from adding the entry in `password keychain`?

This is how `credentials` section of my `.gitconfig` file looks like:

```
[credential]
    helper = !aws --profile my-awesome-aws-profile codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

Comment: same question here.

Answer (score 0):

Find any "gitconfig" file in your system (I had severals) and remove the "osxkeychain" line from it.